# How to hide items from recyclerview as I search in a List<>

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, searchview, android-search

I am using a recyclerView to show a grid of movie posters. The posters are contained in a List<> along with their respective title and so on.

I implemented a searchView widget and I can successuflly get a List of matching results. But I can't hide the other ones.

As you understand I don't want to delete the irrelevant movies from the adapter or the user would not be able to see them again.

This is the code:

```
public class SearchUtils {

    public static List<String> search(List<Show> list, String keyword){
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Show curVal : list){
            String curTitle = curVal.getTitle().toLowerCase().trim();
            if (curTitle.contains(keyword)){
                results.add(curTitle);
            }else{
                results = new ArrayList<>();
            }
        }
        return results;

    }
}
```

ListFragment.java

```
public class ListFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<Show>> {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "ListFragment";
    private static final String ARG_SCOPE = "com.dcs.shows.activity_to_launch";
    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3";
    private TextView tv;
    private ProgressBar pb;
    private int scope;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private ShowAdapter mShowAdapter;
    private SearchView mSearchView;


    public static ListFragment newInstance(int target) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SCOPE, target);
        ListFragment fragment = new ListFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public ListFragment() {
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        scope = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SCOPE);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onCreate@Scope is: " + scope);
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);

        mShowAdapter = new ShowAdapter(new ArrayList<Show>());
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        GridLayoutManager glm = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 4);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(glm);
        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SpacesItemDecoration(8, getActivity()));
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mShowAdapter);
        mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(glm) {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {
                // Triggered only when new data needs to be appended to the list
                // Add whatever code is needed to append new items to the bottom of the list
            }
        });

        pb = (ProgressBar)rootView.findViewById(R.id.progress_view);

        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            // fetch data
            getLoaderManager().initLoader(1, null, this);
        } else {
            // display error
            pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }

        return rootView;
    }



    List<Show> searchList;

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);


        getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        final MenuItem myActionMenuItem = menu.findItem( R.id.action_search);
        mSearchView = (SearchView) myActionMenuItem.getActionView();
        mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                if(!mSearchView.isIconified()) {
                    mSearchView.setIconified(true);
                }
                myActionMenuItem.collapseActionView();
                return false;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                if(s != null || !s.isEmpty()) {
                    for(Show movie : mShowAdapter.getList()) {
                        if(movie.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(s.toLowerCase())){
                            mShowAdapter.add(movie);
                        }
                        mShowAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                } else {
                    mShowAdapter.addItemsToList(searchList, false);
                }
                return false;
            }

        });
        mSearchView.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(new View.OnAttachStateChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(View arg0) {
                // search was detached/closed
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Restoring list: " + searchList + " size: " + searchList.size());
                mShowAdapter.addItemsToList(searchList, false);
            }

            @Override
            public void onViewAttachedToWindow(View arg0) {
                // search was opened
                searchList = mShowAdapter.getList();
            }
        });
    }







    private class ShowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView mImageView;
        public TextView mTextView;

        public ShowHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
            mTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_title);
        }

    }

    private class ShowAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ShowHolder> {
        private List<Show> mShows;

        public ShowAdapter(List<Show> shows) {
            mShows = shows;
        }
        public void add(Show show){
            mShows.add(show);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        public void addItemsToList(List<Show> newShows, boolean append){
            if(append){
                mShows.addAll(newShows);
            }else {
                mShows = newShows;
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public void removeItemsFromList(int index){
            mShows.remove(index);
            notifyItemRemoved(index);
        }


        public List<Show> getList(){
            return mShows;
        }

        @Override
        public ShowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_row, parent, false);
            return new ShowHolder(rootView);
        }
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ShowHolder holder, int position) {
            Show currentShow = mShows.get(position);

            holder.mTextView.setText(currentShow.getTitle());
            Glide.with(getActivity()).load(currentShow.getImage()).into(holder.mImageView);

        }
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mShows.size();
        }
    }



    @Override
    public Loader<List<Show>> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
        //start the loader with the appropriate uri
        //for now it only supports movies+popular
        //it will support movies+top, tv+popular, tv+top.
        Uri baseUri = Uri.parse(BASE_URL);
        Uri.Builder uriBuilder = baseUri.buildUpon();
        uriBuilder.appendPath("movie");
        uriBuilder.appendPath("popular");
        uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("api_key", QueryUtils.API_KEY);
        uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("page", Integer.valueOf(1).toString());

        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "onCreateLoader@URL built: " + uriBuilder.toString());

        return new ShowLoader(getActivity(), uriBuilder.toString());
    }


    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<Show>> loader, List<Show> shows) {
        // Clear the adapter of previous earthquake data
        clearAdapter();

        // If there is a valid list of Shows, then add them to the adapter's
        // data set. This will trigger the ListView to update.
        if (shows != null && !shows.isEmpty()) {
            mShowAdapter.addItemsToList(shows, false);
            mShowAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<Show>> loader) {
        // Loader reset, so we can clear out our existing data.
        clearAdapter();
    }


    private void clearAdapter(){
        List<Show> empty = new ArrayList<>();
        mShowAdapter.addItemsToList(empty, false);
        mShowAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use two lists, one with all the elements (original), and one with just queried elements (this one should use recyclerview adapter). When querying, just select from original list and add them to adapter list, then notify changes. Don't forget to clear adapter list before adding new entries.

Edit: you can try something like this on `onQueryTextChange` method. Adapt for your own wish.

```
if(s != null && !s.isEmpty()) {
   for(String movie : originalList) {
      if(movie.toLowerCase().contains(s.toLowerCase()){
         adapter.add(movie);
      }
      notifyChanges();
    }
  }           
} else { adapter.addAll(originalList); }
```

Comment: Then how do I know when the user isn't searching anymore?

Comment: Then you can add all the item from original list to adapter list with `addAll()` method and then notify changes.

Comment: You have two lists. Let's call them res1 and res2. res1 contains all movies, res2 is empty. When the user does a search, look for all matching entries in res1, add them to res2 and give res2 to the adapter. When the user does another search, look again for every matching entry in res1, add it to res2 and give res2 to the adapter. When the user has stopped searching, add everything from res1 to res2 (`res2.addAll(res1)`) and again give res2 to the adapter.

Comment: Right I'm working with that but I still cant get it to work. Is the way I'm checking for correspondence correct? No item changes at all even after implementing two lists. E: actually it is working ad removing elements correctly but still there are some posters that have absolutely no words in common

Comment: Now i'm getting a ConcurrentModificationException on line `for(Show movie : searchList)`

Comment: That is happening when you change list (add or remove items) that is querried. Do you querry original list and add to adapter list? You can update your question with new code.